# Retrieving data via old DLL in python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, reverse-engineering

I try to use an old DLL from 2001 in Python and there is almost no documentation left.
After some work I could get some function running. But I cannot receive data. My knowledge of DLL and pointers is relatively limited. Heres the problem:

The function `TwixGetMainEntry` expects three parameters

- *ID* of record to retrieve
- *value*. Pointer to string: **This variable will be overwritten with the result. Thats what I am aiming for**
- *Length of buffer*

I do get results, but I cannot decode it properly. The data is probably not UTF-8. And I had to use a 32Bit-version of python.

```py
import ctypes
twix = ctypes.WinDLL("twx.dll")

# Some initialization stuff first
# ...

# Get data
value = ctypes.c_wchar_p("")
twix.TwixGetMainEntry(2, ctypes.byref(value), 1024)

value.value.encode('utf-8') # Returns things like: \xe3\xb9\xb0\xdf\x98\xe3\x90...
```

Tried it with `c_char_p` as well, didn got a result.

Here are some definition of the function in other languages

```
# VB.net
Public Declare Function TwixGetMainEntry Lib "twx.dll" (ByVal nr As Integer, ByVal value As String, ByVal k As Integer) As Integer
# C
int (*TwixGetMainEntry)(int, char*, int);
```

Any ideas what I could try?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please update the question with the unencoded (raw bytes) value of `value`

Comment: They change, but here an example

`value.value.encode('utf-8')` -> `b'\xe3\x82\x90\xc5\xb8`.
`value`-> `c_wchar_p(89699584)`.
`value.value` -> `4294967040`

Comment: Well, if they change, my first guess would be that you are looking at uninitialized memory and/or undefined behavior. Your `value` is a length 0 array, but is advertised as having 1024 bytes, is that correct? You probably want [an array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#arrays) of `c_char`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example.  Note that `c_char_p` is correct for C `char*` and `create_string_buffer` allocates a writable array of `char`.  Use `c_wchar_p` and `create_unicode_buffer` if dealing with `wchar_t*`.

```
import ctypes as ct

# C - default calling convention is __cdecl
# int (*TwixGetMainEntry)(int, char*, int);

twix = ct.CDLL('./twx.dll')      # for __cdecl calling convention
# twix = ct.WinDLL('./twx.dll')  # for __stdcall calling convention

# Declaring argument types and result type helps ctypes check parameters.
# Make sure to match the C prototype.
twix.TwixGetMainEntry.argtypes = ct.c_int, ct.c_char_p, ct.c_int
twix.TwixGetMainEntry.restype = ct.c_int

value = ct.create_string_buffer(1024)  # Need to allocate an array, not just a pointer.
result = twix.TwixGetMainEntry(2, value, ct.sizeof(value))
print(value.raw)   # To view the whole buffer
print(value.value) # to see the null-terminated value of the buffer
```

Comment: That hits the nail on the head. Works perfectly! Many thanks for your help!